# How to understand the world "plain"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, adjectives

> Rough and gray as rock,
> *I'm **plain** as **plain** can be.*
> But hidden deep inside
> there's great beauty in me.
> What am I?

What does "I'm plain as plain can be" mean? Does it mean the first plain is an adjective and the second plain is a noun? The sentence is a comparative sentence that is led by as.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong - both are adjectives. The idiom "As [adjective] as [adjective] can be" is an established usage meaning "very [adjective] indeed".

Since a contrast with beauty is supplied, *plain* here evidently means *ugly* rather than *simple* or *clear.*

Comment: As plain _as it is possible to be_.

Comment: From my schooldays: Latin is a language as dead as dead can be. It killed the ancient Romans, and now it's killing me!

Comment: I'd say not necessarily "ugly" but more "unremarkable", "boring", "inconspicuous".

Comment: @CompuChip - that is not what was asked about.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey no but it was mentioned in this answer, I just disagreed with that it "evidently" means _ugly_.

Comment: @CompuChip - the answer is correct. It says _plain **here** evidently means_...  It clearly identifies an intended contrast -- in the question's quoted text -- between some interior beauty and the speaker's avowed exterior plainness.

Comment: I can imagine 'plain' in the context of a person's appearance meaning 'not beautiful', which is not exactly the same as 'ugly'. Such terminology could be seen as part of the sexist, patriarchal, 'male-gaze' language used to classify women's looks, now, happily, being questioned.

Comment: @CompuChip - Sorry - I was merely trying to distinguish between several senses of the word. I agree that _plain_ means 'not beautiful or attractive' rather than 'ugly' as such.